# Does requestAnimationFrame have its own queue?

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

Does requestAnimationframe have its own queue independent of the event queue? Or do requestAnimationframe callbacks have a higher priority above the event queue?

Comment: According to [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/animation-timing/), `requestAnimationFrame` has a queue of pending requests. That queue is [processed from a task](http://www.w3.org/TR/animation-timing/#processingmodel) which means that it runs in the event queue.

Comment: And while `requestAnimationFrame` has its own task queue [the browser gets to pick which (task queue) source to take a task from on each turn of the (event) loop.](https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules/)