# Which queue is associated with requestAnimationFrame?

Tags: javascript, event-loop, requestanimationframe

Today I was asked this question on an interview. I couldn't answer this question and the interviewer said there was a special queue for requestAnimationFrame callbacks. But I can't find any information on this.

If rAF has it's own queue then why is this queue never mentioned anywhere? We only mention macro- and microtask queues when we talk about Event Loop?

Comment: @Bergi no it's not "one of them". Task queues have their place in the event loop where they get visited, rAF callbacks have another place entirely. They don't participate in the same system. Only one task gets executed per event loop iteration, rAF callbacks are all executed in the same iteration one after the other. Note also how one will deal with browser task (thus not necessarily involving JS), while the other one is ensured to only contain JS callbacks in its list.

Comment: @Kaiido Right, your answer explains this much better than I can in a comment. Afaics, there is no microtask checkpoint after the render callbacks?

Comment: Yes there is one after each callback in https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#clean-up-after-running-script itself from https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#invoke-a-callback-function (step 14). Basically, every time after a bunch of JS is executed, if there is nothing on the callstack anymore, the checkpoint is visited.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> We only mention macro- and microtask queues when we talk about Event Loop?

First, there is no mention of "macro" task in the specs, only [tasks](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#concept-task) and [microtasks](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#microtask) (and then [callbacks](https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#idl-callback-interfaces), more on that later).

Then, almost every [task source](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#task-source) have their own [task queues](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#task-queue) in modern browsers, though they currently don't *have* to. So there isn't just two queues, one that would be the [microtask queue](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#microtask-queue) and another one for all the *tasks*, there are a lot of *task queues* (each `MessagePort` instance can have its own *task queue*). This allows to have various priority for each *task source*. So that UI events can get treated before network ones, for instance.

But `requestAnimationFrame` callbacks are not even queued in a *task queue*. This method schedules a *callback* that (in the specs<sup>1</sup>) isn't invoked from a *task*, but from a special place in the event loop called ["update the rendering"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#update-the-rendering), itself visited only once in a while (generally when the monitor sends a VSync signal and the document is active), which will also fire *scroll* and *resize* events, Web Animation updates, `ResizeObserver` callbacks, etc. and the rendering of the page.

This is important that conceptually all these steps are **not** executed in a *tasks*, because this means that any *task* queued from these callbacks will not get executed before the next rendering, while still ensuring that a `ResizeObserver` callback scheduled from a *resize* event for instance, will be called before.

*Animation frame callbacks* are stored in an [ordered map](https://infra.spec.whatwg.org/#ordered-map), called [the map of animation frame callbacks](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/imagebitmap-and-animations.html#list-of-animation-frame-callbacks). It's not a *queue* per-se, since we can "cancel" the callbacks through the `cancelAnimationFrame()` method. Also this allows getting all the keys at the beginning of the [*run the animation frame callbacks*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/imagebitmap-and-animations.html#run-the-animation-frame-callbacks) algorithm which itself allows to schedule new callbacks from such a callback to the next animation frame without blocking the event loop forever (if it were a queue, the algorithm would keep calling new callbacks endlessly, like it does in the microtask checkpoint).

But that much details is a bit pedantic and unless you're really into this kind of stuff you shouldn't need to know more than

- most native events and Web API callbacks are queued in task queues, which get visited at the beginning of the event loop with a prioritization system,
- all microtasks are executed every time after a callback has been invoked, in a way you can stuck the event loop if queuing microtasks from a microtask,
- some render-related native events and animation frames are treated in their own place in the event loop.

Still, I believe it's good to understand that there is this special *update the rendering* step in the event loop, that is distinct from the other queued tasks in that it doesn't participate in the task prioritization system. I often read that it has an higher priority but IMO it's wrong to say that and given [we'll soon have](https://wicg.github.io/scheduling-apis/) true control over some tasks prioritization, it will grow more important. It also helps understand when the styles recalc are performed and the relationship with (synchronous) DOM updates, and other stuff related to the rendering in a browser. But if you're not applying to a position that involves the details of browser rendering, maybe they just expected the (IMO pretty bad and) colloquial "in the render queue", as is being used e.g. in [P.Roberts's Loupe](http://latentflip.com/loupe/).

<sup>1: Firefox, for one, actually queues tasks even for these, but they do it in a way it's not observable.</sup>

Comment: thank you so much for such a detailed answer. But I still have some questions. 
First,why is the Map of animation frame callback never mentioned anywhere though it's mentioned in the spec. Timers go to task queue, promises go to microtask queue. But nobody tells you where rAFs go to. Any visual representation of Event Loop has only those first 2 queues

Comment: Second. If almost every task has it's own queue then why do everybody always argue about 1 task queue and 1 microtask queue? And where can I read more about task queues prioritization?

Comment: Third. This part of spec (spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-loop-processing-model) makes me think that microtask queue is checked after task queue. Also this article (https://segmentfault.com/a/1190000040945949/en) says so (check paragraph 3.4). Did I misunderstand both an article and the spec?

Comment: 1. The canonical talk about the event-loop would be [Jake Archibald's one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0), it does clearly show that there is a rendering step in the event loop, that is separate from the usual tasks. 2. As hinted by the first point, maybe because your sources aren't the best ones around. Note that in theory it's still possible to have a single queue, but that will soon not be the case. As for task prioritization it's probably a bit sparse, but I guess you can find some material over this [specs incubation](https://github.com/WICG/scheduling-apis).

Comment: 3. As I said to Bergi in the comments under your question, the microtask checkpoint is actually visited after almost every JS script / callback gets executed by the EL. So yes the EL itself has a few call sites, but most of them are actually from https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#clean-up-after-running-script

Comment: Note that in theory it's still possible to have a single queue <- do you mean the case when all calbacks are of the same type? For example, all tasks are setInterval callbacks, no user input, no network events, nothing else.

Comment: No I mean the case an user agent would not do task prioritization at all.

Comment: thank you so much for all your replies. It helped me a lot!! But could you please clarify one more thing to me. The spec says that EL first runs the oldest task from task queue and only after that it runs microtasks. But since microtasks have a higher priority I guess that the oldest task is something special, not a regular timer or smth. Some article said the oldest task is the main script. If it's true that why did it go to the queue when it's a synchronous top-level code? If it's not then what's that oldest task from task queue?

Comment: and if there could be multiple task queues for different task sources, is there different microtask queues - one for promises and another one for mutation observer tasks?

Comment: Microtasks don't participate in the task prioritization system. They are separate and are executed every time the JS call stack is empty + in a few places in the EL in case no script ran as part of the main task. There is no "main script" either from the EL point of view, there might be many <script> elements that will get executed in whatever task spawned the parser (e.g could be a Network task for `<script src=''` or it could also be like any kind of task, e.g. from a `script.textContent = "..."; document.body.append(script)`).  So no, the main task isn't the main script in a browser,

Comment: you probably read an article about node's EL where it would be closer to the reality. So the oldest task is whatever task that got queued first, but note that the specs ask to choose the oldest of any task queue, so it's not necessarul--ily * THE* oldest. And yes, there is only one microtask queue, once again they don't participate in task prioritization and there is no priority system between them. And there must be at most a single queue per task-source, the order of every task queued in the same task-source must be preserved.

Comment: p2 and p2.4 of Processing Model from spec says that if a task queue has any tasks then the first task should be set as EL's currently running task. And only after that EL performs a microtask checkpoint (p3). As I understand it, some task runs first, then all microtasks and then render calbacks. I also see tis diagram in many articles (https://miro.medium.com/v2/resize:fit:720/format:webp/1*PiFyb7IV8vTDCGEeUOWLVQ.jpeg). This diagram corresponds with p2, p2.4 and p3 from spec. But I ran so many tests and I've never had any tasks performed before microtasks. So what could be that task from p.2?

Comment: and since I went into this much detail and I met you who knows so much about EL,what about requestIdleCallbacks? What queue do they go to? Not much information on it on the internet

Comment: P.S. [this article](https://blog.xnim.me/event-loop-and-render-queue#heading-what-are-microtasks) also has a [diagram](https://xnim.me/The%20long%20journey%20to%20the%20runtime%20Part%203%20Event%20loop,%2005203256cba04d22bc89656fdf50f252/Untitled%2016.png) showing that tasks run before microtasks. But it also says "The microtask will be executed as soon as the call stack becomes empty". So does it mean that if I wrote console.log() and then setTimeout(), that console.log would be considered as the first task in a task queue, and not a setTimeout? i.e. sync code is the first task ran by EL?

Comment: That first diagram is plain wrong. The second one is more correct but indeed confusing on the microtask queue. Once again, and for the fourth time on this QA that is not even about microtasks, microtasks are executed every time the JS callstack is empty. A *task* IS NOT as JS script. It's a set of operations the browser has to perform. Some of these include executing scripts, e.g the one responsible for executing the timeout callbacks, or the one for dispatching mouse Events, etc.

Comment: For these the microtask will be visited every time the task meets https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#clean-up-after-running-script You'd need to check every task definition to see when and how it will meet that algorithm. But some tasks just don't execute JS at all, and there will be iterations of the EL where there is no queued task. In such cases the EL needs to have yet another microtask checkpoint outside of the scripts execution to handle the microtasks queued from outside of scripts.

Comment: That's what step 3. is for, but the vast majority of microtasks are executed from *clean after running a script*. But honestly, I can't write a book in comments here. Please if you have further questions, ask clear and concise questions as a new SO post. I'll be out for vacations for a few weeks, but I'll try to answer these if nobody did since then. How and the second article is actually outdated, you can have microtask from `queueMicroTask`

Comment: created a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77054089/need-detailed-explanation-on-event-loop-and-microtask-checkpoints). Please take a look when you have time. Would really appreciate it. And thank you so much for all your replies in this one

Answer (score 2):

`requestAnimationFrame` is specific to the Web API. The callback that is given as argument is collected in an ordered map, which the HTML Standard identifies as a [map of animation frame callbacks](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/imagebitmap-and-animations.html#list-of-animation-frame-callbacks). This map is associated with the HTML document (or the global scope in case of a dedicated web worker).

This map (which can be understood as a queue), gets processed after the current task has completed, including the processing of the microtask queue. This map is consumed as part of the [rendering](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#update-the-rendering) phase of the event loop. The HTML Standard specifies as step 13 of the rendering process:

> 13. For each fully active Document in *docs*, run the animation frame callbacks for that Document, passing in *now* as the timestamp.

So the short answer to "which queue" would be: the map of animation frame callbacks as specified in the HTML Standard.

Comment: I'm pretty new to all those inner mechanisms so I can't catch the meaning of the docs you provided. Does the map of AF callback belong to the same "place" micro- and macrotask queues do?

Comment: The HTML Standard document also mentions the task and microtask queues. I don't know what you mean with "place". In what way do microtask and task queues belong to the same place?

Comment: I mean I've never seen a queue in any visual representation of Event Loop. Also, I've read a ton of articles and watched a lot of videos on Event Loop. And no one ever mentioned the rAF queue (map of animation frame callbacks). So it seems like this map belongs to some other... ummm. system. Like Event Loop has a task queue, a microtask queue and there is a rAF queue somewhere else in a browser. I mean it seems like Map of AFC stands out from task and microtask queue

Comment: Yes, this map (hashmap) is *different* from the task queue and microtask queue. Not sure what you mean with "somewhere else", but yes these data structures take their own space in memory; and as the specifications mention, they are dealt with at different stages in the event loop.

Comment: how is it different from the task queue and microtask queue? Just because it's a map and not a actually a queue? Or there's something else?

Comment: It's a diffetent structure, is processed at a different stage and has a different purpose. What is your doubt?

Answer (score 2):

requestAnimationFrame has [its own queue](https://www.w3.org/TR/animation-timing/#processingmodel) separate from DOM events.  The events are invoked during the rendering phase of the event loop.

The [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/animation-timing/) calls it the "[animation frame request callback list](https://www.w3.org/TR/animation-timing/#dfn-animation-frame-request-callback-list)" -- though I wouldn't expect anyone other than a browser developer to be able to recite that name in an interview situation!    For most web developers, this is browser-internal detail that doesn't normally impact the day to day; I'm surprised this was used as an interview question (unless you're interviewing to work for a browser developer.)

[Here's a duplicate (but unanswered) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32984359/does-requestanimationframe-have-its-own-queue) which has some more links in comments you might find useful.

Comment: It's indeed an odd question to ask at an interview. Although, I'd personally say the most useful outcome would be to identify it's not a normal micro or macro task but separate from them. Even then, it's not something that is...interview material. There are way more interesting questions to ask than something that hardly comes up. And you'd know the answer (essentially, that it's as fast as the refresh/repaint speed) once it does.

Comment: the question was what kind of tasks are micro- and macrotask queus for? What goes where. And then the interviewer asked me "what about rAF callbacks? Do they go to micro or macrotask queue?". I said that I didn't have an answer to that question.
One more question. I've read so many articles and watched so many videos but it's still unclear to me, are micro- and macrotask queues a part of Event Loop (EL) itself? Or they are a part of something else and EL just accesses them when needed? If those queues exist apart from the EL then is AFRC list in the same "group"?

Comment: Honest to god, I've been working on the web for decades and have literally never needed to consider the difference between micro and macro task queues as such; I'd have had no idea how to answer that interview question. Unless you're working in browser internals, that distinction is usually described as synchronous vs asynchronous statements.

Comment: As for your followup question: I have no idea.  Maybe I'm marking myself as an incurious developer, but what you're asking about is under-the-hood implementation details inside the browser's rendering engine that's just not relevant to most web development work, and may even differ per browser implementation. You'd only need to care about that stuff if you're actually implementing a browser or other user agent.