# Need detailed explanation on Event loop and microtask checkpoints

Tags: javascript, event-loop

I'd like to ensure that I properly understand Event Loop and how everything related to it works under the hood. Information on this topic on the Internet is pretty divergent so I want to clarify a few things.

**-- First**. As far as I understand, when I run a script 2 things happen at the same time:

1. synchronous (top-level) code executes right away. But async code snippets (callbacks) will go to the corresponding queues. Sync code will create stack frame(s) in a call stack.
2. Event Loop starts running in a backgroud but doesn't do anything yet. For now it just waits for the sync code to finish.

Then, after the sync code is finished, it's time for a microtask checkpoint. And that's the reason why everyone says that a microtask queue has priority over task queue in Event Loop. But in fact EL hasn't managed any queues yet. It's just an "after script" microtask checkpoint. [In the spec this step is called clean up after running script](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#clean-up-after-running-script) - if call stack is empty then microtask checkpoint is performed.

And only after that "after script microtask checkpoint" the actual Event Loop comes into play. The EL itself processes queues in the following order:

1. **task queue** - grabs only one task and performs it
2. **microtask queue** - another "microtask checkpoint". Runs all
   microtasks until the queue is empty
3. **render queue**

So we can't really say that microtask queue has a higher priority over a task queue in the Event Loop. It's quite the opposite - every cycle of Event Loop starts from checking the task queue.

So this piece of code

```
console.log("sync code");

setTimeout(() => console.log('task'));

Promise.resolve('microtask').then(console.log);
```

will be executed in the following order: **(1)**

```
"sync code"  // script
"microtask"  // "clean up after running script" checkpoint, not Event Loop
"task"       // first step of EL
-----------  // (second step of EL) microtask queue is empty - promise has already been executed outside EL
-----------  // (third step of EL) render queue is empty because we don't have an appropriate callback
```

but not because **(2)**

```
"sync code"  // script
"microtask"  // first step of EL since higher priority
"task"       // second step of EL
-----------  // third step of EL - render queue is empty because we don't have an appropriate callback
```

But some resources (even trust-worthy ones like javascript.info) say that [the sync script is a Task put into task queue](https://javascript.info/event-loop#summary). From this point of view the code above is executed in the following order: **(3)**

```
// Event Loop starts doing it's job right away
// no "clean up after running script" microtask checkpoint
"sync code"  // first step of EL - running the oldest task from task queue
"microtask"  // second step - executing all microtasks
"task"       // going back to the first step of EL
```

This order contradicts the spec. And that's what confuses me the most about how EL works. So I want to clarify a few things:

- Is order ***1** wrong? Or does javascript.info gives wrong information
  and order ***3** is the wrong one?
- Is the sync script considered as a task by EL and put into task
  queue? Some sources say that sync script never belongs to any queues
  and is not a task of any kind. Some other resources say the opposite.
- From the spec I can say that EL runs all microtasks every time call
  stack empties. If order *1 is the correct one then is there a
  microtask checkpoint after the render queue?
- If there is, then does it mean EL manages queues in the following
  order: task -> microtask -> render -> microtask -> (another cycle of
  EL starts) task -> etc... Just like in Node.js Event Loop
- Which queue do **requestIdleCallback**s go? rAF callbacks have higher
  prority rather than rIC ones hence could be run at different points
  of time. Do both types of callbacks belong to the same render queue
  but could be executed at different points of time since render queues
  is actually a map and not a FIFO queue?

**-- And second**. [Spec says there's a clean up after running script microtask checkpoint](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#run-a-module-script) after executing a module. Also as I can tell from [this proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await/pull/51#issuecomment-466956043) EL processes microtask queue between executing modules. As a result the example

```
// a.mjs
import "./b.mjs";
import "./c.mjs";
console.log("a");
 
// b.mjs
console.log("b1");
await 0;
console.log("b2");

// c.mjs
console.log("c");
```

outputs this when we run a.mjs

```
"b1"  // from module A we go to module B and run synchronous console.log("b2").
      // But we don't run console.log("b2") right away. 
      // Instead we put it into microtask queue because it goes after await. 

"b2"  // we exit module B. We're in a module A again. And now it's time for a microtask 
      // checkpoint (clean up after executing a module). Here console.log("b2") is executed
    
"c"  // again from module A we go to module C and run synchronous console.log("c")
    
"a"  // we exit module C. No microtasks to run. So we run synchronous console.log("a") from module A
```

Seems reasonable. And follows the rules of spec. But if modify code a bit:

```
// a.mjs
Promise.resolve("before import").then(console.log);
import "./b.mjs";
import "./c.mjs";
console.log("a");
 
// b.mjs
console.log("b1");
await 0;
console.log("b2");
Promise.resolve("b3").then(console.log);

// c.mjs
console.log("c");
```

The result would be:

```
"b1"  // same
"b2"  // same
"c"   // same
"b3"  // executes after we exit module C, in a "clean up after executing a module" microtask checkpoint
"a"   // same explanation as in a previous example
"before import"  // ???
```

The question here is why "before import" runs at the very end? Not in a microtask checkpoint after module B? Even async console.log("b3") executes earlier despite the fact that we created this promise long after "before import" promise

Comment: How it works "under the hood" is implementation-dependent.

Comment: Not silly for the slightest, maybe it could be improved a bit by focusing on a single point though, it's currently quite broad. But I really don't see how this could attract opinion based answers as one of the close voters stated, nor how one could assume it would be implementation-dependent when you clearly ask about what the specs say. (Ps as I told you I may not be able to compose an answer myself before quite some time, I'll try though).

Comment: "*why "before import" runs at the very end?*" - that's a separate question, for which you should create a separate post. But the short answer is that any code in a module gets evaluated only after all imports are ready, no matter where in the module the `import` statements are placed.

Answer (score 0):

One important thing to remember is that a [*task*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#concept-task) is specs concept to represent a set of operations that the browser has to perform, this is never your scripts directly, and these operation may not involve JS at all, even if most tasks will at some point [*invoke*](https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#invoke-a-callback-function) some JS, that's just some part of it.
So if we take your first example of a script making calls to Web APIs that will queue new tasks, that script is itself called as part of the Event Loop (EL) processing. What part is hard to tell without a clearer example, but for instance for an inline script executed in a `<script>` tag at page load, that would certainly be the document's navigation's network task that did start the Document's parsing algorithm, so while it's quite deep in the various specs algorithms, you can still go back to that first step of the EL processing model that picked up the task.

But if we keep that one task in mind, then we can see that the microtask queue will indeed be visited right after our script got executed:

```html
<script>
console.log("sync 1");
queueMicrotask(() => console.log("microtask 1"));
</script>
<script>
console.log("sync 2");
queueMicrotask(() => console.log("microtask 2"));
</script>
```

But no task got queued in between both these scripts got executed. But as you correctly noticed, the [clean after running script](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#clean-up-after-running-script) has been called, and this will trigger the microtask checkpoint, even in the same EL iteration.

So yes, your understanding was almost correct, except that your first bullet is itself *probably* part of a *task*.
We can **definitely** say that microtasks do not have higher priority than any tasks, there is just no prioritization system for microtasks, and they just don't participate in the tasks's one at all. They are separate.

So the correct diagram for the above snippet would be

```
"network task" // document load 
 - ... do MANY things
 - "Script execution" // still in the main task we run the first <script>
 - "microtask checkpoint" // clean after running script
 - "Script execution" // still in the main task we run the second <script>
 - "microtask checkpoint" // clean after running script
 - // Continue parsing of the document
"end of task"
"microtask checkpoint" // This one handles the microtasks that would have been queued outside of a JS script
------ // In this case that would probably be DOM mutations for instance
------ // But most of the time, that actually does nothing
... few more boring steps
"update the rendering" // first rendering we'll enter here, but it's not a given later
 - "execute render-related event callbacks", for each one, trigger a "microtask checkpoint" (clean after running scripts)
 - "execute rAF callbacks", for each one, trigger a "microtask checkpoint" (clean after running scripts)
 - "execute more render-related callbacks"
 - "render"
"update idle time"
"pick a new task if any and do it all again"
```

Note that if at the next iteration there is no *task* available, it will just continue to the next steps, still updating the rendering when necessary, so every iteration of the EL doesn't necessarily pick a *task*.

Idle callbacks are specified by [another specs](https://w3c.github.io/requestidlecallback/), so that doesn't really help understand where they're executed from, but [they ask](https://w3c.github.io/requestidlecallback/#start-an-idle-period-algorithm) to

> [Queue a task](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#queue-a-task) on the queue associated with the idle-task [task source](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#task-source),

And this *start an idle period algorithm*, is itself triggered by the EL 8th step, right after *update the rendering*, when it meets the deadline conditions. So the callbacks are queued in a task, what triggers the algorithm to queue that task is part of the EL, just like animation frames handling.

---

For the second part of the question, that may better fit an entirely different question, but this is due to how are evaluated module scripts and is not really related to the EL.
Basically the `import` clauses are hoisted, so it's like they were always moved to the top of your script, like `function` declaration in classic scripts.

Comment: Ps: I'm not sure why you thought javascript.info is any trustworthy, for what I can see it's ran by individuals that don't seem related to any official web platforms.